# Site was designed in x cart. but some functions got deprecated

Tags: php, regex, php-5.4, x-cart

D/All,

I am getting the below error in my web site. i think some functions has been deprecated due to higher version PHP 5.4.32.
My site was designed in x cart. All the servers are upgraded to the latest C panel and php versions
The site is working fine the contents are not changed. only the below error getting while opening product page.

I am unable to fix the issue. request any one to help on this.

```
Option  Required    Currently    Status     Comments
Operation system    -   Linux   OK   
PHP version     5.4.32  5.4.32  OK   
Perl-compatible regular expressions     On  On  OK   
PHP Server API      CGI unknown OK   
MySQL support is ...    On  On  OK   
safe_mode   0   0   OK   
register_long_arrays    1   0   Failed  Please check php.ini to correct problem
disabled functions list     Not (exec, popen, pclose, ini_set)  , , dl, , , exec, , , passthru, , , pcntl_exec, , , pfsockopen, , , posix_kill, , , posix_mkfifo, , , posix_setuid, , , proc_close, , , proc_open, , , proc_terminate, , , shell_exec, , , system, , , posix_setpgid, , , posix_setsid, , , proc_get_status, , , proc_nice, , , show_source, , phpinfo  Warning Some functionality may be lost
file_uploads    1   1   OK   
upload_max_filesize     2M  200M    OK   
sql.safe_mode   0   0   OK   
magic_quotes_runtime    0   0   OK   
magic_quotes_sybase     0   0   OK   
register_globals    1   0   Warning Emulation is used

Please contact your host administrators and ask them to correct PHP-settings for your site according to the requirements above.

Directory   Permissions Required    Comments
(root) /home/bracelet/public_html   40755   xx755   
(customer) /    40755   xx755   
(admin) /admin  40755   xx755   
(provider) /provider    40755   xx755   
(partner) /partner  not exists  xx755
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the output, the first thing is that you have to enable the `register_long_arrays` which is currently disabled